# Designing Color Customizer

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, jscolor

I found a lot of resources about my question, but I'd just like opinions based off of a high level overview of what I'm trying to do.

Basically, I'm using a combination of Javascript, and HTML to build a customizer for a friends' website. I should start by saying that I have some HTML experience but this is the first time I'm using Javascript (I am experienced with Java). The ultimate goal will be something like a customizer to allow users to select the parts of a bicycle and change their colors to place custom orders.

I've got the various parts of the bike as images files, and I'm using this jscolor color picker found at: http://jscolor.com/examples/#example-showing-hiding   to allow the user to select a color from the color map. My plan is to layer a given part (photo) on top of a copy of the same photo, and fill only one of them, like layering in Photoshop. This way, the part fills in the correct shape, instead of filling as an entire square of the image file. As the cursor moves, the color should change in realtime. Once done, they can save the part and the color record will be kept on the back-end.

As I'm new to Javascript and not that experienced with HTML, I'm finding it a bit challenging to get this on the right track. So I'm hoping for some advice from some people who are experienced with HTML/Javascript/CSS to point me in the right direction to get this going along a better track than it is currently. I wasn't sure how to "phrase" what I'm trying to do.

The three main parts I'm addressing:

1. Using HTML buttons to load a different bike part (essentially load a separate image file).
2. Adding the color from the jscolor picker to the image of the selected part.
3. Saving the state of the part when the user clicks a Save button.

I will continue to search the forums as I already saw a few leads similar to what I want to do, but I mostly want to know if my approach seems feasible for what I'm attempting to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using normal HTML buttons will make things complex for you.
I think leveraging HTML5 Canvas API is a better way to approach this problem. Canvas is the HTML5 element for helping out you do the graphics manipulations using JavaScript. Learn more about canvas [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).
You can make use of a library such as [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using SVG to get the outline of the object/parts. However, now I'm trying to define the shapes better. I have just the outlines being colored properly, I want to make it more detailed so i think I need to play around with the paths a little more.

Comment: Well... I'm not that experinced with SVGs :) . A friend of mine did a side project similar to this, he was building an 'apparel customizer' he went with canvas. SVG would work too, I guess. Good luck.

Comment: The SVG seems to get the right outline of the shape properly, but it looses the details on the fill. Instead of seeing the shape filled with a color, I'm seeing the outline of the shape filled with a solid color. All the intricate details of the shape are lost. :( ...So now I'm experimenting with the SVG settings to keep the details.

Comment: The site I'm working on doesn't allow Javascript unless its built inside of the HTML code in a <script> block, so I'm trying to stay away from heavy Javascripting